# Conditional GAN for domain translation

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am training a GAN to perform style transfer from two different image domains (source `S` and target `T`). Since I have available class information I have an extra `Q` network (except `G` and `D`) that measures the classification results of the generated images for the target domain and their labels (a LeNet network) and propagate the error to generator as well with `D`. From the convergence of the system I have noticed that `D` is starting always from 8 (the loss function error of the `D` network) and slightly drops until 4.5 and the `G` loss function error is starting from 1 and quickly drops to 0.2. The loss function of `D` and `G` I am using can be found [here](https://github.com/r0nn13/conditional-dcgan-keras) while the loss function of `Q` network is categorical cross-entropy. The error plots over the iterations are:

[image]

The loss function of D and G are:

```
def discriminator_loss(y_true,y_pred):
      BATCH_SIZE=10
      return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(y_pred), K.concatenate([K.ones_like(K.flatten(y_pred[:BATCH_SIZE,:,:,:])),K.zeros_like(K.flatten(y_pred[:BATCH_SIZE,:,:,:])) ]) ), axis=-1)

def discriminator_on_generator_loss(y_true,y_pred):
     BATCH_SIZE=10
     return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(y_pred), K.ones_like(K.flatten(y_pred))), axis=-1)

def generator_l1_loss(y_true,y_pred):
     BATCH_SIZE=10
     return K.mean(K.abs(K.flatten(y_pred) - K.flatten(y_true)), axis=-1)
```

Does it make sense that the error function of D is always that high? What is the explanation of the errors of `D` and `G`? Is it that the loss of `D` should be small in the beginning and rise after the iterations? Is it a good idea to restrained the `D` over `G` with a loss threshold? Finally, during the training does it make sense to calculate the error from the loss function over a validation set and not from my train set that I am using? (instead of directly using train_on_batch use fit and then evaluate on a test set).

**EDIT:**

For the losses I think that the loss of `discriminator` and the `discriminator_on_generator` are the normal loss functions of GANs, right?

Answer (score 0):

Let G be Generator and D be Discriminator. Initially, both the D and G are untrained. Now, let us assume that the D learns faster than the G does. So, after a while, G can distinguish between samples that are sampled from the real data distribution and those which are sampled from the generator. Finally, G catches up and learns to emulate the real data distribution. Now, D can no longer differentiate between samples that are sampled from the real data distribution and those which are sampled from the generator.

[image: Combined G D losses]

So, we initially start with a high loss for both D and G (Region I). Then the loss for D decreases faster than the loss for G does (Region I to II). As the loss of G continues to decrease, the loss of D increases (Region II). Finally, both the losses reach an equilibrium value and the training is thus completed (Region III).

[image: D loss]
[image: G loss]

Comment: What I am experience though it exactly the opposite.

Comment: There's a typo, It should be : "Now, D can no longer differentiate between samples that are sampled from the real data distribution and those which are sampled from the generator." (and not G)